# Testing EventMachine timers with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, eventmachine

I have a method like this:

```
def my_method(id)
  EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(10) do
    my_other_method(id)
  end
end
```

(Obviously simplified.) How would I write an rspec test to check `my_other_method()` is called? Or that this happens repeatedly? When I call `my_method()` from within a test then the test just freezes because of the EM timer.

I've seen [em-rspec](https://github.com/stevegraham/em-rspec) and [em-spec](https://github.com/schmurfy/em-spec) but can't see how to use them for this particular test. The latter seems to assume your EM timers are written in the tests themselves, rather than in the code you're testing? (But maybe I've misunderstood?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use these [examples](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames).
For example

```
# test that method is called 10 times
MyObject.should_receive(:my_other_method).exactly(10).times

# stub 10 calls for method my_other_method
MyObject.should_receive(:my_other_method).exactly(10).times.and_return(val1, val2, ..., val10)
```

You can find other examples following by link above

Comment: I don't see how that's going to help with testing something that gets called every 10 seconds or so, rather than 10 times?

Comment: sorry I think I did not catch your question